# How to write files using Node.js on Microsoft Windows?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have following code to create a file in Node.js:

```
config.fs.writeFile('Click/Click|'+page._id+'.json', JSON.stringify(page),'utf8', function (err) {
                        if (err) return console.log(err);
                        mCB();
                    });
```

it is working on Ubuntu but not on Windows where I get the following error:

> ```
> { [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, 
> open 'C:\Users\keyur-designer\Desktop\nodejs\Click\Click|abffa463-dc9e-11e6-bc97-c12c7e70a906.json']   
> errno: -4058,  code: 'ENOENT',  syscall: 'open',
> path: 'C:\\Users\\keyur- designer\\Desktop\\nodejs\\Click\\Click|abffa463-dc9e-11e6- bc97-c12c7e70a906.json' }
> ```

Can anyone help me.

`Click` is my folder name.

I have also tried with `'./Click/Click|'+page._id+'.json',`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The vertical bar (or pipe) `|` is a forbidden character in a filename on Windows file system. However, it is allowed on Unix file systems.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Reserved_characters_and_words)

Comment: Good catch. Not noticed that.

Comment: This is the only correct answer. I've faced this problem myself on Ubuntu and Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to write a file into a directory named `Click/`. If this directory does not yet exist you will get the above error.

For got path formatting look at Mykolas answer.